# RCCManager set root controller, react native navigation.h

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, root, react-native-navigation

I did the same steps like
https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/Installing
but I gets an error "console error , error while starting app: TypeError undefined is not an object evaluating RCCManager.setRootController"

```
import { Navigation } from 'react-native-navigation';

import HomeScreen from './src/Home';
import ProfileScreen from './src/Profile';


Navigation.registerComponent("projectTwo.HomeScreen",()=>HomeScreen);
Navigation.registerComponent("projectTwo.ProfileScreen",()=>ProfileScreen);


Navigation.startSingleScreenApp({
     screen: {
      screen: "projectTwo.HomeScreen",
      title: "Home"
  },

})
```

Comment: Did you set root inside AppDelegate.m

Comment: Yes I did it like below.. and paste the same content in index.ios.js, android and index.js
NSURL *jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];

Comment: https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/Installing please check here

Comment: I did this twice still I'm facing this issue ! what should I do ?

Comment: Please check `didFinishWithLaunching` you need to update this method

Comment: wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/Installing check here

Comment: If 'react-native-navigation' isn't working use this 'react-navigation'